# Bootstrap 4 from source: 'npm run dist' throws error

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am trying to compile from source, and have been successful with everything in the official instructions, except when I do "npm run dist", it blows up on me, throwing a bunch of errors, starting with one from js-lint. Anyone know what might be going on?

Here is what I have followed: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/build-tools/#tooling-setup

This is on OSX 10.12.3

Node v8.9.4

NPM 6.4.0

```
    npm run dist

    > bootstrap@4.1.3 dist /Users/me/Desktop/bootstrap 4 test 2/node_modules/bootstrap
    > npm-run-all --parallel css-main js


    > bootstrap@4.1.3 css-main /Users/me/Desktop/bootstrap 4 test 2/node_modules/bootstrap
    > npm-run-all --parallel css-lint css-compile --sequential css-prefix css-minify css-copy


    > bootstrap@4.1.3 js /Users/me/Desktop/bootstrap 4 test 2/node_modules/bootstrap
    > npm-run-all js-lint* js-compile js-minify js-copy


    > bootstrap@4.1.3 css-compile /Users/me/Desktop/bootstrap 4 test 2/node_modules/bootstrap
    > node-sass --output-style expanded --source-map true --source-map-contents true --precision 6 scss/bootstrap.scss dist/css/bootstrap.css && node-sass --output-style expanded --source-map true --source-map-contents true --precision 6 scss/bootstrap-grid.scss dist/css/bootstrap-grid.css && node-sass --output-style expanded --source-map true --source-map-contents true --precision 6 scss/bootstrap-reboot.scss dist/css/bootstrap-reboot.css


    > bootstrap@4.1.3 js-lint /Users/me/Desktop/bootstrap 4 test 2/node_modules/bootstrap
    > eslint js/src js/tests build/


    > bootstrap@4.1.3 css-lint /Users/me/Desktop/bootstrap 4 test 2/node_modules/bootstrap
    > stylelint --syntax scss "scss/**/*.scss"


    Oops! Something went wrong! :(

    ESLint: 5.4.0.
    No files matching the pattern "js/tests" were found.
    Please check for typing mistakes in the pattern.

    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! errno 2
    npm ERR! bootstrap@4.1.3 js-lint: `eslint js/src js/tests build/`
    npm ERR! Exit status 2
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! Failed at the bootstrap@4.1.3 js-lint script.
    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     /Users/me/.npm/_logs/2018-08-20T22_08_53_067Z-debug.log
    ERROR: "js-lint" exited with 2.
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! errno 1
    npm ERR! bootstrap@4.1.3 js: `npm-run-all js-lint* js-compile js-minify js-copy`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! Failed at the bootstrap@4.1.3 js script.
    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     /Users/me/.npm/_logs/2018-08-20T22_08_53_093Z-debug.log
    ERROR: "js" exited with 1.
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! errno 1
    npm ERR! bootstrap@4.1.3 dist: `npm-run-all --parallel css-main js`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! Failed at the bootstrap@4.1.3 dist script.
    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     /Users/me/.npm/_logs/2018-08-20T22_08_53_179Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compile from source, you should clone our repository or download it thanks to Github.

For our last release: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/v4.1.3

You cannot compile Bootstrap with what we share because we only share what's needed for folks who don't want to compile Bootstrap themself

Comment: Thank you so much for sorting this out. I was completely at a loss. I just followed your instructions, and it worked beautifully.

I retraced my steps, and I think what may have happened was that I had installed the tools, and was trying to compile on a copy of Bootstrap 4.1.3 that I had gotten via npm. Good to know.